# Facebook Messenger API - Possible to generate the "Persistent Menu" user-specific?

Tags: php, facebook, dynamic, menu, facebook-messenger

I'm developing a Messenger BOT by using the Facebook Messenger Platform. I was able to create a **Persistent Menu** by following [their guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/messenger-profile/persistent-menu).

I used `CURL` to create that menu. Which means, the same Persistent Menu is applied (appeared) to everyone.

Now, i want to know whether that Persistent Menu is customizable for different users.

As a simplest example, let's say i want to put **User's Name** on one of that menu items, like:

- `Hello John Cena!`
- - `View my Credits`
- - `View Bills`
- - `Order History`
- `Latest News`
- `Promotions!`

Obviously, i need to do more meaningful stuffs. Like, putting different Web Links based on User. Show/hide some menu items based on User. Etc.

Please kindly suggest.

(Note: i'm using PHP for backend.)

Comment: No that is not possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Persistent Menu is part of Messenger Profile. Messenger Profile is the central store for your bot's properties. All Messenger Profile properties are common for the bot and cannot be made user specific. However you can personalize greeting text with user's name using `{{user_full_name}}`.
**Note**: Not sure whether `{{user_full_name}}` will work on persistent menu.

Comment: Tested with `{{user_full_name}}` and nope, it doesn't work. So it is pretty much impossible to have the persistent menu customized. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: You can customize per locale.